# Get subdomain and query database for results - Meteor

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, meteor, dom-events

I am pretty new to Meteor now.

I want to:

1. get the sub-domain of the url
2. check if a client exists matching the sub-domain
3. if client exists query the database and get some results (say client settings) from the database.

I am sure that this would be a piece of cake if we use MongoDB, however, we have to move an existing application (built on PHP) that has MySQL backend.

I have found a package [numtel:mysql](https://atmospherejs.com/numtel/mysql) for meteor and I have added it to the project.

Here is the source code written so far:

```
if(!Session.get('client_details')) {
    var hostnameArray = document.location.hostname.split('.');

    if(hostnameArray[1] === "localhost" && hostnameArray[2] === "local") {
        var subdomain = hostnameArray[0];
    }

    if(subdomain) {
        currentClientDetails = new MysqlSubscription('getClientDetailsFromUrl', subdomain).reactive();
        Tracker.autorun(function() {
            if(currentClientDetails.ready()) {
                if(currentClientDetails.length > 0) {
                    var clientDetails = currentClientDetails[0];

                    Session.setPersistent('client_details', clientDetails);
                    var clientId = clientDetails.id;

                    if(!Session.get('client_settings')) {
                        clientSettings = new MysqlSubscription('clientSettings', clientId).reactive();
                        Tracker.autorun(function() {
                            if(clientSettings.ready()) {
                                if(clientSettings.length > 0)
                                    Session.setPersistent('client_settings', clientSettings[0]);
                                else
                                    Session.setPersistent('client_settings', {});
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*the `session.setPersistent` comes from [u2622:persistent-session](https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session) to store Sessions on client side*
and here is the publish statement:

```
Meteor.publish("getClientDetailsFromUrl", function(url) {
    if(typeof url === undefined) {
        return;
    }

    var clientDetails = Meteor.readLiveDb.select(
        'select * from clients where client_url = "'+ url +'"',
        [{table: 'clients'}]
    );

    return clientDetails;
});


Meteor.publish("clientSettings", function(clientId) {
    if(typeof clientId === undefined) {
        throw new error('ClientId cannot be null');
        return;
    }

    var clientSettings = Meteor.readLiveDb.select(
        'select * from client_settings where client_id = ' + clientId, [{
            table: 'client_settings'
        }]);

    return clientSettings;
});
```

and the database is initiated as

```
Meteor.readLiveDb = new LiveMysql(<MySQL Settings like host, user, passwords, etc>);
```

### Problem

I get `client_details` into the session successfully, however, cannot get `client_settings` into the session. End up with an error:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
Error: Subscription failed!
    at Array.MysqlSubscription (MysqlSubscription.js:40)
    at app.js?6d4a99f53112f9f7d8eb52934c5886a2b7693aae:28
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js:294)
    at Tracker.Computation._recompute (tracker.js:313)
    at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:452)
    at onGlobalMessage (setimmediate.js:102)
```

*I know the code is messy and could get a lot better, please suggestions welcome*

Comment: What kind of object is *clientSettings[0]*?

Comment: @MichelFloyd, it is the result of the database query